# Using multiple editable elements in HTML5 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the  to be able to type data into a page, press a button to save the data, then be able to close and re-open the page with the saved data.

I have been able to do this with the code below with 1 text area, but if I use multiples, it only displays the last entered data.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("CPU")
var editElem = document.getElementById("RAM")
var editElem = document.getElementById("HDD")
//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
document.getElementById("CPU").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits
document.getElementById("RAM").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits
document.getElementById("HDD").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">
<label>Processor : </label>
<div id="CPU" contenteditable="true"></div><br><br><br>
<label>RAM : </label> 
<div id="RAM" contenteditable="true"></div><br><br><br>
<label>Hard Drive : </label>
<div id="HDD" contenteditable="true"></div><br><br><br> 
<input type="button" value="SAVE" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
<div id="update"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You keep reassigning everything to the same variable... You need to separate that all out.

Comment: ...and the same problem with `localStorage` - you're using only one property, not three.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 3 different variables for each of the 3 inputs, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xtat0oa6/5/

javascript

```
 function saveEdits() {

    //get the editable element
    var editElem1 = document.getElementById("CPU")
    var editElem2 = document.getElementById("RAM")
    var editElem3 = document.getElementById("HDD")
      //get the edited element content
    var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
    var userVersion2 = editElem2.innerHTML;
    var userVersion3 = editElem3.innerHTML;

    //save the content to local storage
    localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
    localStorage.userEdits2 = userVersion2;
    localStorage.userEdits3 = userVersion3;

    //write a confirmation to the user
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";

  }

  function checkEdits() {

    //find out if the user has previously saved edits
    if (localStorage.userEdits1 != null || localStorage.userEdits2 != null || localStorage.userEdits3 != null){
    document.getElementById("CPU").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1
    document.getElementById("RAM").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2
    document.getElementById("HDD").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits3}
  }
```